# What is the difference between webdriver.Firefox() and webdriver.Firefox(<path to gecko executable >) in selenium?

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver, geckodriver

I looked through the selenium 3 for python documentation but still couldn’t get the difference between these two different driver calls.

```
webdriver.Firefox()
```

and

```
webdriver.Firefox(<path to gecko executable >)
```

when using Selenium?

Since I’m working on a web scraping project this could help me a lot .

Answer (score 1):

### webdriver.Firefox()

As per the documentation in [selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver) the following line is the *default constructor*.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

While you use the *default constructor* your script/program expects that the underlying *OS PATH* variable to contain the *absolute path* of the *GeckoDriver* which will **start a new local session of Firefox Browser**

---

### webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')

Again, as per the documentation of [selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver) the complete/full signature of **webdriver.Firefox()** is as follows:

```
class selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver(firefox_profile=None, firefox_binary=None, timeout=30, capabilities=None, proxy=None, executable_path='geckodriver', options=None, service_log_path='geckodriver.log', firefox_options=None, service_args=None, desired_capabilities=None, log_path=None)
```

This achieves the following:

- Starts a new local session of Firefox.
- Based on the combination and specificity of the various keyword arguments, a capabilities dictionary will be constructed that is passed to the remote end.
- The keyword arguments given to this constructor are helpers to more easily allow Firefox WebDriver sessions to be customised with different options. They are mapped on to a capabilities dictionary that is passed on to the remote end.
- As some of the options, such as firefox_profile and options.profile are mutually exclusive, precedence is given from how specific the setting is. capabilities is the least specific keyword argument, followed by options, followed by firefox_binary and firefox_profile.
- In practice this means that if firefox_profile and options.profile are both set, the selected profile instance will always come from the most specific variable. In this case that would be firefox_profile. This will result in options.profile to be ignored because it is considered a less specific setting than the top-level firefox_profile keyword argument. Similarily, if you had specified a capabilities[“moz:firefoxOptions”][“profile”] Base64 string, this would rank below options.profile.

So incase your *Test Suite* includes *testcases* with multiple version of *GeckoDriver*, *options*, *Firefox Profiles* and *Capabilities*, you can always specifically mention them while initializing the new *WebDriver* instance and *Web Browsing* session.

As an example, if you place *geckodriver.exe* v0.21.0 within `C:\\geckodriver_0_21_0\\` you can mention as follows:

```
# Windows OS style
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\geckodriver_0_21_0\geckodriver.exe')
# Linux OS style
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='path/to/geckodriver')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define the path for the driver, Functional call look for the file in the path and works accordingly. Second function `driver.Firefox() / driver.Chrome()` looks for existing software in the system. if the browser is not present you'll be getting following error.

```
 WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

My take is always use absolute path for the driver definition.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
binary = FirefoxBinary('path/to/installed firefox binary')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

Comment: `firefox_binary` has nothing to do with `geckodriver`