# How to use FirefoxDriver in Selenium?

Tags: maven, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I created a MavenTestProject in Eclipse with these dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In MyTest01.java I tried to instantiate the FirefoxDriver:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

and I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property;...
```

I tried this code, but it didn't work also:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "selenium-firefox-driver-3.141.59.jar");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\ofiman\eclipse-workspace\MavenTestProject\selenium-firefox-driver-3.141.59.jar
```

What can I do to get an instance of my FireFoxDriver?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have gecko driver installed?
is it in your path?

Comment: The Maven Dependencies contain the selenium-firefox-driver and some other drivers for browsers.

Comment: Check this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/selenium-using-java-the-path-to-the-driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdr?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path where your gecko driver is in your local");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Let me know if this does'nt work

Answer (score 0):

`webdriver.gecko.driver` needs to be a path to [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

Comment: What's the difference between geckodriver and selenium-firefox-driver?

Comment: @ofiman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197632/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-firefox-and-webdriver-firefoxpath-t

Comment: @ofiman Gecko driver is the current most updated driver for newer versions of Firefox

Comment: @ofiman selenium-firefox-driver is the library that uses geckodriver. Geckodriver is essentially Firefox without the GUI.