# Setup Selenium & Python on Eclipse FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]

Tags: python, eclipse, selenium, installation, path

I'm trying to setup Selenium with Python and Eclipse on my home computer but I keep getting the following 2 trace back errors.  I know part of it is that the "geckodriver.exe" file is not in the correct path but I don't know where to move it to so its correct and what the `"FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"` error refers to.

Program:

```py
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    user_name = "123@gmail.com"
    password = "Password123"
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")
    element = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
    element.send_keys(user_name)
    element = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
    element.send_keys(password)
    element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    element.close()
```

Console Error Msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,<br /> 
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\eclipse-workspace\PyDev1\PyDevPackage\PyDevModule.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Comment: the error is referring to the "PATH" environment variable in Windows: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm  (You can also specify a specific path for geckodriver when initializing...: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197632/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-firefox-and-webdriver-firefoxpath-t )

Comment: Thank you so much!